# Why my button in MVC doesn't work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, button, visual-studio-2013

I've got this code:

```
 @model IEnumerable<PamelaFundacionFinal.Models.Escuela>

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }
  <h2>Escuelas registradas</h2>

  <p>
 <button name="Edit" class="btn btn-default"><b>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")</b></button></p>
  <table class="table">
     <tr>
       <th>
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombre)
        </th>
         <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Direccion)
          </th>
          <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Telefono)
          </th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Direccion)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Telefono)
            </td>
            <td>
   @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Escuela_ID })
  <button name="Edit" class="btn btn-default">
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Escuela_ID })</button>
 <button name="Edit" class="btn btn-default">
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Escuela_ID })</button>
    </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
```

Don't worry, everything is referenced to their own controller to make the opperations, my issue is that I've got two cases:

1. I'm writing in `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Escuela_ID })` a reference to another controller, so I can create a new one, but it's simple text
2. Then, I'm trying to put that reference into a button, so it looks nice: `<button name="Edit" class="btn btn-default">@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Escuela_ID })</button>` but it doesn't work.

I know that I'm not writing this correctly, but I need help because I'm new with this language and I don't really know exactly how is the syntax. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server to run the database (The connection with database is running perfectly, it's not an issue with the database).

Comment: Give the `<a>` tag created by the helper a class name and use css to style it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style your `<a>` tag that is generated by the Html helper.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Escuela_ID },
                   new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```